# SonarQube with Azurepipelines showing no results

Tags: sonarqube

I configure Azure pipelines with react native. I need to analyse the code using SonarQube. Builds are succeeded.But SonarQube shows no issues. The Publish Quality Gate Result shows ['No analysis found in this build! Please check your build configuration.']